# Multer Image Not loaded on Production Build React?

Tags: node.js, express, multer

I am using MERN to create simple eCommerce I am facing error when i am in production mode. The file uploads on the specified folder but don't get load on front-end.

Server.js

```
import path from 'path'
import express from 'express'
import dotenv from 'dotenv'

const __dirname = path.resolve()

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/frontend/build')))

  app.get('*', (req, res) =>
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'frontend', 'build', 'index.html'))
  )
} else {
  app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('Api running....')
  })
}

app.use('/uploads', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/uploads')))
```

Upload routes and code

```
import path from 'path'
import express from 'express'
import multer from 'multer'

const router = express.Router()
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination(req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, '/uploads')
  },
  filename(req, file, cb) {
    cb(
      null,
      `${file.fieldname}-${Date.now()}${path.extname(file.originalname)}`
    )
  },
})

function checkFileType(file, cb) {
  const filetypes = /jpg|jpeg|png/
  const extName = filetypes.test(path.extname(file.originalname).toLowerCase())
  const mimeType = filetypes.test(file.mimetype)

  if (extName && mimeType) {
    return cb(null, true)
  } else {
    cb('Images only with jpg, jpeg, png ')
  }
}

const upload = multer({
  storage,
  fileFilter: function (req, file, cb) {
    checkFileType(file, cb)
  },
})

router.post('/', upload.single('image'), (req, res) => {
  res.send(`/${req.file.path}`)
})

export default router
```

When i inspect the file it says on the src the image cant load check the image=> [image: SnapShot of frontend loading Sceen with inspect on the image element]

Now when i am in development mode the same code works as expected and the image loads.  [image]
What might the possible error please help me. **Thank you in Advance.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your production server is not meant to store files because that will lead to increase in consumption of server resources. So it will automatically delete any files/images that you have uploaded to the production server.

And why would you want to store files on production server, just use a database or file storage system like s3 bucket.

Comment: I just explained it, what else do you want to know about?

Comment: I mean how do i do it ?

Comment: You can use mongodb Atlas to store your images if you want( it provides free space upto 500mb).

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error and what I did is just switching the place the of the upload folder on the top. You want to make sure that all the image be available before the **build** of frontend request any image from it.

```js
import path from 'path'
import express from 'express'
import dotenv from 'dotenv'

const __dirname = path.resolve()
// Put it here
app.use('/uploads', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/uploads')))

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/frontend/build')))

  app.get('*', (req, res) =>
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'frontend', 'build', 'index.html'))
  )
} else {
  app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('Api running....')
  })
}
```